# $f$ is holomorphic function on an annulus , show that $f(z)=0$ for all z in the annulus if some conditions are met

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I guess the next problem should be addressed somehow with Laurent series:

Let $0<r<s<\infty$, $A=A_{r,s}(0)$ and $f\in\mathcal{O}(A)$. Suppose that $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{lim}f(z_n)=0$  either for every sequence $\{z_n\}\subset A$ with $\vert z_n\vert \rightarrow r$ or for $\{z_n\}\subset A$ with $\vert z_n\vert \rightarrow s$. Show that $f(z)=0$ for all $z\in A$. Investigate weather this conclusion remains valid in either limiting case $r=0$ or $s=\infty$.

I thought that I can write f as a power series and then, from knowing it goes to 0 for all sequences in the form appears above  I can say that its converging in $B_r(0)$ but I didnt succeed to get through with it

Comment: Zeroes of analytic functions are isolated. (May be useful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juest extend $f$ to $\overline{A_{r,s}}$ with $f(z)=0$ when $\lvert z\rvert=r$ or $\lvert z\rvert=s$. This extension is continuous and $\overline{A_{r,s}}$ is compact. So, the absolute value of the extension has a maximum on $\overline{A_{r,s}}$. Now, apply the maximum principle.

Comment: The continuous extension will in general only work on one of the boundary circles (under the given assumption). But even if it extends continuously, why would the maximum principle help?

Comment: using maximum principle on f and maximum principle on 1/f gives the desired outcome, but i dont understand how to show that the extension is continuous, can you please show how you prove it?

Comment: @LukasGeyer Why do you claimit will work only on one of the circles? It works for both of them.

Comment: @RoniBenDom Because when $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=z$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(z_n)=f(z)$.

Comment: The assumption is that the boundary limits exist on one of the circles, not for both of them. Anyway, that is really not the main point. Assume that your function is $0$ for $|z|=r$, but non-zero for $|z|=s$. By the maximum principle the maximum of $|f(z)|$ is then attained for some $|z|=s$. How does this show that $f$ is constant?

Comment: Just to illuminate the point: Harmonic functions also satisfy the maximum principle. The function $u(z) = \log |z|$ on $1<|z|<2$ is harmonic and vanishes for $|z|=1$, yet it is not constant. The maximum principle is not the way to go here...

Comment: @LukasGeyer I think that you misunderstood the “or” in the statement of the problem. It says that when a sequence $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of elements of $A$ is such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lvert z_n\rvert=r$ **or** $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lvert z_n\rvert=s$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(z_n)=0$. So, there is one and only continuous extension to $\overline{A_{r,s}}$, which is the extension which takes the value $0$ on both circles.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: I don't think this is the way this is meant, though you would be correct if that is the assumption. However, even under the weaker assumption with zero boundary values on one of the circles the conclusion is still valid (though not due to the maximum principle.)

Comment: When $f=0$ only on one of the circles, it easily follows that one of the functions in the Laurent representation $f=f^{+}+f^{-}, f^{+} \in\mathcal{O}(D_s), f^{-} \in\mathcal{O}{(\mathbb{C}-\bar{D_r})}$ is zero, which means $f$ extends holomorphically past the zero boundary circle and that means $f$ identically zero by the identity theorem; $z, \frac{1}{z}$ show that the result is not true in the limit for either $r\to 0$ or $s \to \infty$ in this only one "circle" case